# Read specific file extension from a list using if R

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to make an if statement to seperate what my code will do if I have text files in my list or whatever file extension.

I tried this

```
if (extension == txt) { .... }
else {...}
```

but it didn't work.

I cannot find how to do it and other commands like sys.globe or pattern didn't work.

Comment: object extension not found

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dir` function to list the files in your working directory (which you can set using `setwd`). `dir` has a `pattern` parameter that allows you to filter files using regular expressions.

So for instance:

```
setwd("/path/to/files")
# Finds all files ending with .txt
# Note: the $ indicates the end of the string
# You need to escape the dot using \\ because it is a special
# regexp character.
files <- dir(pattern="\\.txt$")
# Finds all files beginning with F
files.2 <- dir(pattern="^F")
# Finds all files containing the string abc
files.3 <- dir(pattern="abc")
```

For more help see `?dir` and `?regexp`

Once you have your file list you can use the lapply` function to do whatever you need to do with the file.

For instance:

```
lapply(files, function(f)
       {
       res <- read.table(f)
       ...
       })
```

Edit following comment.

If you want to process all files, but treat txt files differently you can still use `dir`, get all the files and then use a regular expression to get extensions.
For instance:

```
all.files <- dir()
for (f in all.files) # or you can use *apply as well
    {
    if (length(grep("\\.txt$", f) > 0))
       {
       print(paste(f, "is a txt file"))
       }
    else
       {
       print(paste(f, "is not a txt file"))
       }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to do it with a list because my code has a lot of things to do after that so I want to do it with "if". Can you suggest something?

Comment: Why can't get a list and then use `lapply` on the list? I have added an example of how to do that

Comment: I need the "if" statement because if my files are txt the process will be different just for 1 line in the code. After that all the process is the same! So I dont want to have 2 different lists cause how I will continue?